# Replace the comma with vertical bar |, except when inside double quotes, and remove double quotes

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, csv

File1

```
12584,"Capital of America, Inc.",,HORIZONCAPITAL,USA,......etc
25841,"Capital of America, Inc.",,HORIZONCAPITAL,USA,......etc
87455,"Capital of America, Inc.",,HORIZONCAPITAL,USA,......etc
```

Output

```
12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

I have a csv file,  which i have to conver into a text file delimited with pipe(|)
I have done the shell script `sed 's/^/"/;s/,/|/g;s/$/"/' $File > $Output`

But the problem is the field "Capital of America, Inc." contains a comma, that's also replaced by the pipe (|).
So I just wanted to replace all, with pipe except not inside the value is given double quotes " ".

Is there any shell script to do this?

Comment: See also [Substitute every comma outside of double quotes for a pipe](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/450810) (not exact duplicate)

Comment: There are any number of CSV parsers/generators out there that do a better ,more correct job than you could do with a quick shell script. Just import the CSV with one separator and re-generate it with another.

Answer (score 21):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvformat -D '|' file.csv
12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

`csvkit` is a collection of CSV manipulation/querying tools written in Python.  These do proper CSV parsing and `csvformat` may be used to replace the default comma delimiter with any other character.  The utility will make sure that the result is properly quoted according to CSV rules.

Comment: Quoting rules seem odd for this tool. A line like `one   ,  "one""two""t33"   ,   two` is converted to `one   |"  ""one""""two""""t33""   "|   two` with default quoting rules, but after playing with it for a while I am not able to get the (imVHo) correct output of `one   |one"two"t33|   two` (because repeated quotes `"` represent a single `"`). Even adding the `-b` option. You may like my solution.

Comment: @Isaac But that removes the spaces in the second field. All double quotes in your example's second field is part of the data since there's a space before `"one"` and after `"t33"`. Double double quotes (`""`) are used to embed double quotes in quoted fields, and your second field is not quoted (due to the spaces). Removing the spaces (creating a quoted field) yields `"one""two""t33"` after reformatting with `csvformat`, which looks correct to me.

Comment: Hmmm. I could understand the logic which claims that all characters (even spaces) delimited by commas are part of the field (only except when quotes start and end the field). I am not sure what should be the final rule.

Comment: @Isaac The rule is that a quoted field starts with a double quote. Embedded double quotes should be doubled, and fields containing embedded double quotes should themselves be quoted. See points 5, 6 and 7 in the "Definition" section of RFC 4180: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: In that RFC there is no mention nor definition of  spaces **outside** of a quoted field. The only mention of spaces is to say: *Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored.* in point 4. There is no way in which we will resolve this correctly, there are many conflicting definitions everywhere. In the RFC [this definition](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm) is linked. That definition states: (1) *Leading and trailing space-characters adjacent to comma field separators are ignored.*  (Cont…)

Comment: (Cont.…) (2) *Fields with leading or trailing spaces must be delimited with double-quote characters.*. I can live with either of the **interpretations**. Let's agree to not agree on this point.  … … I also have decided that an awk (and also sed or grep) solution is a bad idea, CSV records could extend for several lines and awk (sed and grep) are line-oriented. Making it difficult (at the very least) to implement a reasonable solution. +1 :-)

Answer (score 8):

At least on Debian-based systems, you should be able to install the OCaml-based `csvtool`

```
$ csvtool -u '|' cat file.csv
12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

You could also use Perl's `Text::CSV` module:

```
$ perl -MText::CSV -lne '
  BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new()} 
  print join "|", $p->fields() if $p->parse($_)
' file.csv
12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

Comment: you have `cat` randomly placed in your `csvtool` command.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor in this context `cat` is the internal `csvtool` command - the usage (at least the version I have) is `csvtool [-options] command [command-args] input.csv`

Comment: Fail if a quoted field has spaces: `12584,"  Capital of America, Inc.",,HORI` yields `12584|"    Capital of America, Inc."||HORI` (quotes not removed).

Comment: @Isaac are you sure about that? The perl version should (silently) skip lines that it fails to parse. (FYI you can likely *make* it parse your - broken - example by instantiating the parser with additional options like `escape_char => "\\", allow_loose_quotes => 1`.)

Comment: Hmm. correct, the error is also for csvtool. A line like `87455|"Capital of"" America"", Inc."||HORIZ` yields `Fatal error: exception Csv.Failure(5, 2, "Non-space char after closing the quoted field")`.

Comment: But the PERL solution (which does silently reject lines regarded as incorrect) fails if (1) there is an space between the `"` and the next `,` (2) If a field contains double quotes `"` (but accepts repeated double quotes `""`). (As far as I have tested)

Comment: @Isaac that seems to be beyond the scope of the original question - the `Text::CSV` module provides several parser options for dealing with such cases, however the comments section are not really the place to explore those IMHO

Comment: There is no option to "deal" with a simple space like `one,"two" ,three`

Comment: Really? `echo 'one,"two" ,three' | perl -MText::CSV -lne 'BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new({ allow_whitespace => 1 })} print join "|", $p->fields() if $p->parse($_)'` seems to work for me

Comment: No, because that will also remove whitespace from `888    ,one,"two" ,     three`

Answer (score 2):

To fix your problem:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="|";} {print $1,$2","$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' Test | tr -d \"
```

to generalized problems like this, GNU `awk` has a *FPAT* special variable to describe fields:

```
awk -vFPAT='[^,]*|("[^"]*")' -vOFS='|' '{$1=$1;print}' Test | tr -d \"
12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

with `awk` and `sed` tools, you do not need an extra package.
**EDIT**
as [Issak](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458297/replace-the-comma-with-vertical-bar-except-when-inside-double-quotes-and-rem/458303?noredirect=1#comment833379_458303) mentioned, I update my answer:

```
awk -vFPAT='[^,]*|(["].*["])' -vOFS='|' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' Test | sed 's/\"//g'
```

Comment: This will always preserve the second comma on a line, no matter where that comma occurs.  Assuming that the file is larger than shown, it is fair to expect that some instances of the second field won't contain commas, or that it may contain more than one comma.

Comment: my answer is correct for this question, anyway I edit it.

Comment: This fail if a line like `87455,"Capital of" America", Inc.",,HOR`.

Answer (score 2):

Using SED:

**Option 1:**

```
sed -e 's#,\([^ ]\)#|\1#g;s#"##g;s#|,#||#g' file

12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

- `\([^ ]\)` replace all comma which is not followed by space.
- Then remove `"` and replace the comma prefixed by `|`.

usually in a context, a comma will be with space. If not in your case, try the below code.

**Option 2:**

```
sed -e  's#^#\n#;:a;s#\n\([^,"]\|"[^"]*"\)#\1\n#;ta;s#\n,#|\n#;ta;s#\n##;s#"##g' file

12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

Comment: @ Isaac i hope you wouldn't try my second option yet. let me know if you have any concerns then.

Comment: @Petro i hope you wouldn't try my second option yet. let me know if you have any concerns then.

Comment: Regular expressions weren't designed for processing nested elements differently. While it's sometimes possible to have it parse such statements because of the non-regular extensions most engines have nowadays, it is still so easy to get wrong. It's just not a good tool for the job.

Comment: For me sed -e  's#^#\n#;:a;s#\n\([^,"]\|"[^"]*"\)#\1\n#;ta;s#\n,#|\n#;ta;s#\n##' file
not working, not removing " " between Capital of America, Inc.

Comment: @Juhan try my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

With standalone `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{"(.*?)"|,}{$1 // "|"}ge' < "$File" > "$Output"
```

(it assumes the values don't contain `|`, `"` or newline characters).

Answer (score 1):

## `awk`, one character at a time

Examine each line of input, one character at a time.  Toggle a counter `q` between `0` and `1` each time you encounter a double-quote mark `"`, so that `q` equals `1` inside each pair of double-quote marks (ie, before each *closing* double-quote mark).  Then, depending on `q`, change commas `,` into pipe characters `|`.  After each line has been evaluated, print the modified line.

```
awk '{
  m=""
  q==0
  for (n=1;n<=length($0);n++) {
    p=substr($0,n,1)
    if (p=="\"") { p="" ; q=(q+1)%2 }
    if (p=="," && q==0) p="|"
    m=m p
    }
  print m
  }' file.csv
```

Input:

```
12584,"Capital of America, Inc.",,HORIZONCAPITAL,USA,......etc
25841,"Capital of America, Inc.",,HORIZONCAPITAL,USA,......etc
87455,"Capital of America, Inc.",,HORIZONCAPITAL,USA,......etc
```

Output:

```
12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

Answer (score 0):

With a very short Python  script using `csv` module:

```py
import csv,sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    csvr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in csvr:
        print('|'.join(line))
```

That works as follows:

```
$ python3 csvfile.py input.csv
12584|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
25841|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
87455|Capital of America, Inc.||HORIZONCAPITAL|USA|......etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using python pandas below:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('input.csv',quotechar = '"',skipinitialspace=True)
df1.to_csv('output.csv', sep='|', index=False)
```